# Android parse JSON and avoid app crashing if JSONException

Tags: android, json, exception

my app sends a POST request to a server and gets a response using JSON format.

Sometimes my JSON response is "null" (if the request goes in time out).
In that case I need to notify the user about the timeout (dialog or toast) and avoid the app to crash.

**How do I handle correctly the JSONException and avoid the app crash?**

Thank you!
Marco

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you're asking how do you catch an exception and show a dialog box?

Comment: Is there a reason a try-catch block wouldn't suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to avoid the crach of your app while parsing your json , try this :

```
if (jsonResponse == null) {
       // notify user
} else {
      try {
         // parse json here.
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error on the response", 3000).show();
      }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

check if your json response is null. only then parse the json.

```
if (jsonResponse == null) {
       // notify user
} else {
      // parse json here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get full exception :

```
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        jsonString = out.toString();
    }

    }catch(ConnectException e){             
    // handle your exception here, maybe something like
        Toast.makeText(context,"Error!",5000).show();
        finish(); 

    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```